# mysql , PDO and php with multiple select search

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

i have a table data of shop product list

```
 id | product name | shop Name 
 ----------------------------
 1  | Suger        | Ram Store 
 -----------------------------
 2  | Oil          | Suraj Store 
 -------------------------------
 3  | Batter       | Ram Store 
 ------------------------------
 4  | Maida        | Ram Store 
 --------------------------------
 5  | Rice         | Ram Store 
 -------------------------------- 
 6  | Suger        | Suraj Store 
--------------------------------
 7  | Oil          | Ram Store 
 -------------------------------- 
 8  | Rice         | Suraj Store
```

now user search multiple value :

**search.php**

```
  <form method="post" action="results.php">
    <select name="product[]" multiple>
        <?php $showp=$db->query("SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY productname ASC"); 
            $showte = $showp->fetchAll();
            foreach($showte as $runshow){
            $productname=$runshow['productname'];
            $productid=$runshow['id']; ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $productname; ?>"><?php echo $productname; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search"/>
</form>
```

now is result.php

```
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        foreach($_POST['product'] as $productselect){
        echo $productselect."<br>";
        $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE testid LIKE '$productselect' ");
        $new = $query->fetchAll();
            if(count($new)){
                foreach($new as $show){ 
                    echo $show['shopname']; 
                    echo "productname = ".$show['productname']."<br/>"; }
            }
            else{ echo "No Result Found<br/>"; }    
        }
    }/* serech if isset close */
```

now select user is suger , oil , batter

user result show is : --

```
   suger 

   suraj store 
   ram store

   oil 

   suraj store 
   ram store

   batter 

   ram store
```

result show is ok but i want show in shop list like

```
   suraj store 

   suger
   oil 


   ram store

   suger
   oil 
   batter
```

please say how i do this  ..

thanks in advance for your support

Comment: print_r($new); is what?

Comment: foreach($new as $show){ 
                    echo $show['shopname']; 
                    echo "productname = ".$show['productname']."<br/>"; }
            } should shop_name first and name second only // this code is correct

Comment: where is the problem and how to complete this work ..

Comment: print_r($new); can you show the output

Answer (score 1):

Do not echo results of query in result.php
Instead make array which will contain shop names and products associated with them.

Instead of:

```
echo $show['shopname']; 
echo "productname = ".$show['productname']."<br/>";
```

Do sth like this:

```
$shopProducts[$show['shopname']][] = $show['productname'];
```

And on the very end of file print results:

```
foreach ($shopProducts as $shopName) {
    echo $shopName . ":\n";
    foreach ($shopProducts[$shopName] as $product) echo "$product\n";
}
```

Comment: I need additional information, because illegal offset type error usually shows up when object is being used as key in array, and code I've suggested should not produce such error. Probably some other things you've done with code are producing this error.